# Flipcountdown js not able to reinitialise

Tags: javascript

Is there a way to reinitialise the following javascript plugin?
I went through the plugin and it doenst seem to have a way.

I tried:

```
   clock.unbind().removeData();
   clock.flipcountdown({
      size: 'sm',
      showDays: false,
      beforeDateTime: update_date,
```

https://github.com/xdan/flipcountdown

Comment: clock.flipcountdown({
       beforeDateTime: update_date,
});

Comment: what is the value of the update_date ?